# How do I get date in MM/DD/YYYY format in windows phone and how to separate date by "/"

Tags: c#-4.0, datepicker, windows-phone-8-emulator

How to separate date by "/" means 02/04/2014,
I am getting output like this 02-04-2014, but I want like this:

```
4/2/2014
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/` gets replaced by your culture's date separator which seems to be `-`.

Read: [The "/" Custom Format Specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#dateSeparator):

> The "/" custom format specifier represents the date separator, which
>   is used to differentiate years, months, and days. **The appropriate
>   localized date separator is retrieved from the
>   DateTimeFormatInfo.DateSeparator property of the current or specified
>   culture**.

You can use [`CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture.aspx):

```
string dateAsString = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this sample

```
 DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
 Console.WriteLine(now.ToString("d"));
```